# Make item delegate in QTableView not transparent

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate

I issued in problem with custom item delegate for QTableView.

That problem is completely illustrated by that screenshoot:

[image]

We can see item content behind item delegate editor. What is the best way to hide that content or make item delegate not transparent? (how I can get background color/brush for edited row?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let your editor to paint its own background by enabling the autofill background property:

```
editor->setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

Comment: Thank you. It partially solved the problem, but now widget's background is white, when the other part of the row is grey.

Answer (score 0):

widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: #eee;");