# PyQt5 QTableView cell editing behaviour - superimposition of original value

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm messing around with tables in PyQt for the first time and am running into some unexpected behaviour when editing cell values.

Specifically when I type data, it appears over the top of the existing cell data (so if the cell originally had '123' in it, and I type '456', I end up with 2 lots of 3 characters, one over the top of the other - at least until I press enter).

Just to be clear, I have no issues with setData writing the changes to the model, or with the changes being reflected in the table after editing is complete - that's all happening fine. The only problem is seeing the original value and the new value I'm typing in occupying the same space until editing finishes.

So presumably what I want to do is alter my existing data method:

```
def data(self, index, int_role=None):
    row = index.row()
    column = index.column()
    if int_role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return str(self._data[row][column])
    elif int_role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        return str(self._data[row][column])
    else:
        return None
```

so that it somehow recognizes if the cell it's being asked to provide data for (in DisplayRole mode) is currently being edited, and if so, return an empty string instead of the actual data (as the EditRole branch of the code is being called as well at the same time and is happily handling display duties until editing is finished).

I've had a look around the QT docs but cannot work out how to do this.

Edit: After ceppo's comments, I've looked at creating a new ItemDelegate - but [looking into it further](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52418/PyQt4.QtGui.QItemEditorFactory) it looked like I would be able to instead switch out the itemEditorFactory in the existing one - specifically I added the following to my code:

```
newEditor = QLineEdit()
newEditor.setAutoFillBackground(True)
ief = QItemEditorFactory()
ief.registerEditor(QVariant.String, LineEditorCreator())
tableView.itemDelegate().setItemEditorFactory(ief)
```

with LineEditorCreator defined as follows:

```
class LineEditCreator(QItemEditorCreatorBase):
    def __init__(self):
        QItemEditorCreatorBase.__init__(self)

    def createWidget(self, parent):
        wdgt = QLineEdit(parent)
        wdgt.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        return wdgt

    def valuePropertyName(self):
        return "String"
```

however now I get a Segmentation fault as soon as I try to edit a cell value. Putting a print statement in as the first line in the createWidget statement shows it not ever getting executing - some print statements in the createWidget shows that the Segmentation faults occur even before the first line of createWidget executes (though the __ init __ method completes fine).

Ceppo also said that the behaviour I'm experiencing could be due to a bug (in Qt, PyQt or something else underlying) - I'll be replacing my current Ubuntu 15.10 installation with 16.04 soon so with some luck that will solve the issue entirely.

Comment: Probably some problem with the editor background, try to add a `BackgroundRole` and return a color (e.g. red), if the editor have a transparent background, when editing, you will see that color.

Comment: I've added another elif branch to the clause for `int_role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole`, and added `return QColor(255,0,0,255)` inside it - this does indeed turn the background for all cells red, all the time, whether they're being edited or not - but that doesn't really help towards the goal of making the cell contents invisible while the editor is visible. I understand that if I can set the editor's background to be the window background's color that would work, but I don't know how to set the editor's background color in the EditRole branch (or how to reference the editor at all).

Comment: It was to found the root of the problem (maybe a bug in your qt version? I don't have this problem) ;) Anyway you cannot change the background of the editor from the model directly, but you can write a simple `LineEdit` editor-delegate and then you can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805756/make-item-delegate-in-qtableview-not-transparent/22806076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 did indeed fix the problem.

My 16.04 distro has python3-pyqt5 and other qt packages with versions all around 5.5.1 - I did check but didn't think to jot down the versions of those packages in my 15.10 installation before wiping it - but packages.ubuntu.com says 5.4.2 is the current version for 15.10 and that sounds familiar.

So if anyone else with QT 5.4.2 is running into the same thing, upgrading to 5.5.1 might be worth a try - either by upgrading to a newer distro or attempting to find and use a backport of the newer QT version.

Thanks Ceppo93, it was a good guess.